# How to create an inline border that maintains a 4 pixel distance from the edge using SVG

Tags: css, svg

I need to create an inline border within a TD tag that is always 4 pixels from the edge. "outline-offset" is NOT supported in IE11, so I'm trying to create a  in SVG and set that as the background-image of the TD, but I'm unable to keep the 4 pixel padding on the right and bottom as SVG width needs a number or percentage:

Any ideas on how to pull this off in SVG using an svg file? Or maybe another technique? "viewbox" helps with scaling, but I haven't found a way to keep the 4 pixel padding when TD is resized on column width change.

I'm trying to do this without inserting a DIV tag into the TD and setting it's border. Just pure CSS in the TD without adjusting the DOM.

Many thanks :)

[inline cell border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CAoe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a `::before` pseudo element.

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.inset-border::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="inset-border">7,321</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Paul! :)